# How to change page inside CATCH block (Node.js & Express )?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, puppeteer

I have this small code below which goes to IMDB website to scrape movie title. The code actually works fine with the small `catch` for basic error handling.

```
app.get("/", function(err, req, res){
  function handleError(err) {
    console.log('Ohhhh nooo');
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  (async ()=>{
    let movieURL= "https://www.ximdb.com/title/tt1375666/?ref_=hm_tpks_tt_i_1_pd_tp1_cp";
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(movieURL, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
    const movieData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let movieTitle = document.querySelector('div[class="TitleBlock__TitleContainer-sc-1nlhx7j-1 jxsVNt"] > h1').innerText;
      let movieRating = document.querySelector('span[class="AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1 iTLWoV"]').innerText;
      return{movieTitle, movieRating}
    });
    res.render("index2", {movieData});
    console.log(movieData);

    await browser.close();
    return;

  })()
  .catch(handleError);
});
```

I have intentionally change IMDB to "ximdb" for error. When I start this script, the console logs error messages. However,

1. the loading sign on the browser does not stop. How can I stop script/loading when error happens?
2. I want the page on the browser to change when error happens. This code below is what I want to do, but it doesnt work and it gives error(`(node:696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined`).

```
  function handleError(err, res) {
    console.log('Ohhhh nooo');
    console.log(err.message);
    res.render("index2");
  }
```

Comment: What error does the code produce...? "doesn't work" is a useless problem description.

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Add your catch to the page.evaluate promise, currently it errors there and res.render is never invoked.

```
const movieData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let movieTitle = document.querySelector('div[class="TitleBlock__TitleContainer-sc-1nlhx7j-1 jxsVNt"] > h1').innerText;
      let movieRating = document.querySelector('span[class="AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1 iTLWoV"]').innerText;
      return{movieTitle, movieRating}
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err);
        res.render(some error page);
    })
```

As the rendering of your existing page will probably not work without the movie data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have done as you said but problem still persists. catch block doesnt let me to render a new page. Apparently my code is broken somewhere. I will take a deeper look. Thank you again.

Comment: You can try doing the same for each await in your code, with different error messages to find where it gets stuck.
Otherwise putting a console.log in between every other line could help you identify until where your code is running.

Comment: I will do as you say, to put more console.log lines to find error. Thank you for the advice

Comment: I found the problem, when I take out `err` from the ` app.get("/", function(err, req, res){` then it works fine. I dont why but that was the solution.